# Eclipse plugin is listed with other plug-ins, but UI contributions are missing

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I wrote two Eclipse plugins that work fine when I use Eclipse to run them in another instance of Eclipse. I'd like to distribute the plugins to a relatively small number of people for feedback and was hoping that the dropins folder would provide a quick and dirty solution. When I put the plugins in the dropins folder of my Eclipse installation (Indigo), I see the plugins listed with other plugins in the installation details. The UI contributions are missing and I haven't been able to find any error messages in the logs or otherwise.

As stated, I'm looking for a quick and dirty solution. I intend to build an update site in the future, but would prefer to invest time into that only after getting feedback on the plugins because this is a side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your plugin is loaded, but isn't started.  A 'quick and dirty' solution is to have it use the org.eclipse.ui.startup extention point so it is activated on startup.

Another possibility is that your UI additions just aren't activated for the perspective, which you can fix by running Window > Customize Perspective.

Comment: I was able to get this working with the org.eclipse.ui.startup extension point. Thanks!