# The UI menu provided by my Eclipse plugin fragment is missing. How do I determine why?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I've been creating a plug-in fragment in Eclipse 2019-06. When I test it by spawning a secondary runtime Eclipse application, the desired "Generate JUnit Tests" menu item appears.

[image]

I then created a plugin following the directions in the [Plug-in Development Environment Guide](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_plugins.htm?resultof=%22%70%6C%75%67%2D%69%6E%22%20%22%70%6C%75%67%22%20%22%65%78%70%6F%72%74%22%20) and copied the jar (JunitGenerationFragment 1.0.0.201908210930.jar) into my Eclipse dropins directory.

I started Eclipse like so:

```
eclipse -clean -console -consoleLog -debug .options
```

where my .options file contains:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true
```

Eclipse starts up, but without my menu item.  When I look in the log file for my workspace, I see no mention of "JUnitGenerationFragment", however, I do see things in the console window pertaining to the fragment:

```
[p2] Wed Aug 21 09:42:48 EDT 2019 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1a59d098-9074-4562-b6a2-2280982401d7] [reconciler] [dropins] Interesting feature or bundle added: C:\Tools\Eclipse\jee-2019-06\eclipse\dropins\JunitGenerationFragment_1.0.0.201908210930.jar
...
[p2] Wed Aug 21 09:43:07 EDT 2019 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1a59d098-9074-4562-b6a2-2280982401d7] [reconciler] Adding IU: JunitGenerationFragment 1.0.0.201908210930
[p2] Wed Aug 21 09:43:07 EDT 2019 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1a59d098-9074-4562-b6a2-2280982401d7] [reconciler] Adding IU property: JunitGenerationFragment 1.0.0.201908210930->{org.eclipse.equinox.p2.type.lock=1, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.internal.inclusion.rules=OPTIONAL, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins=true}
...
[p2] Wed Aug 21 09:43:12 EDT 2019 - [Start Level: Equinox Container: 1a59d098-9074-4562-b6a2-2280982401d7] [reconciler] [plan] JunitGenerationFragment 1.0.0.201908210930
```

As near as I can tell, everything looks good.  (Well, except for having no menu item.)  I then try seeing if there is an obvious problem via the osgi console:

```
osgi> diag JunitGenerationFragment
JunitGenerationFragment [3]
  No resolution report for the bundle.
```

I'm not sure what that means or what to do about it.  The only other piece of potentially diagnostic information I can provide is that the JUnitGenerationFragment shows up in my Plug-ins list of the IDE, but has a different icon than the others.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to further diagnose and fix my problem!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I attempted was to use the org.eclipse.ui.startup extention point so it is activated on startup, following the advice on this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791017/eclipse-plugin-is-listed-with-other-plug-ins-but-ui-contributions-are-missing?rq=1).  That didn't solve my problem.

I discovered the Plug-in Registry view, which is reachable via `Window -> Show View -> Other`, then, in the Show View dialog, choosing `Plug-in Development -> Plug-in Registry`.  I right-clicked on my plug-in and selected `Diagnose`.

[image: Plug-in Registry]

I got the following report:

[image: Missing bundle]

I edited the Dependencies in my META-INF/MANIFEST.MF to use a different version of org.eclipse.jdt.junit.

Finally, I took a belated look at my Problems pane.  Among the many warnings that I typically ignore, was one pertaining to my problem:

[image: plug-in warning]

Mea culpa.  I updated my build.properties to include fragment.xml:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/, ., fragment.xml
```

Now, I can install my plug-in fragment and get my menu.